# python-pptx dataLabels to show percentage (%) symbol for data points properties

Tags: python, python-pptx

while generating column stacked 100% chart.
if suppose series values are (1, 8, 1). I would expect to see segments with data labels 10%, 80% and 10%.

However, with the code below I see 100%, 800% and 100%.

below is code used.
plot = chart.plots[0]
plot.has_data_labels = True

```
data_labels = chart.plots[0].data_labels
data_labels.font.size = Pt(6)
data_labels.number_format = '0%'
data_labels.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.CENTER
```

when data_labels.show_percentage=True is set instead of data_labels.number_format = '0%' it just shows number but not percentage symbol.

[column stacked 100 chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTGPZ.png)

I want to show data labels with percentage like below

[data labels with % symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B0F0.png)

when data_labels.number_format = '0%' is used 40 is shown as 4000% 3->300% , 60->6000%

below is data used

[data used for chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3mAY.png)

[when data_labels.number_format = '0%' is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN0TL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `data_labels.show_percentage = True` and change the number-format to `"0\%"` (note the backslash before the percent-sign.

```
data_labels = chart.plots[0].data_labels
data_labels.show_percentage = True
data_labels.number_format = "0\%"
```

Comment: Yes I tried this.  but it just shows number but not % symbol.
        plot = chart.plots[0]
        plot.has_data_labels = True
      
        data_labels = chart.plots[0].data_labels
        data_labels.font.size = Pt(6)
        data_labels.show_percentage=True
        data_labels.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.CENTER

Comment: Does it show the "right" number, like `10` instead of `10%`? or is it the wrong number like `1`?

Comment: What if you then add back in the `data_labels.number_format = '0%'`?

Comment: when data_labels.number_format = '0%' is used 40 is shown as 4000% 3->300% , 60->6000% , attached image in above question.

Comment: Ah, okay, so I believe what you need is `data_labels.number_format = "0\%"`, note the backslash. This causes a "%" character to be appended without multiplying the value by 100.

Comment: Thanks. data_labels.number_format = '0\%' it worked.